# Can I repeatedly cast (spam) concentration spells?

Tags: dnd-5e

I was reading about the "Create Bonfire" cantrip. If I cast this upon the square a creature is standing in, they must succeed on a Dexterity saving throw or take 1d8 fire damage. This sounds like a fairly powerful cantrip (1d8, and it can harm over time, too). I was thinking of taking this as my "damage" cantrip. It seems like a better spell than let's say Produce Flame

Could I simply spam this concentration spell to cause 1d8 damage per turn? If so, could I conceivably cast it repeatedly on the same square?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Yes**, you can cast "Create Bonfire" as your action each turn.

The effect of the previous casting will end, as you are casting another spell requiring concentration, but you can keep casting new spells and forcing Dex saving throws (and lighting the forest on fire). The only requirement for casting it is ground you can see in range, so maybe not the best choice in the plane of air.

As an aside, I invite you to consider other cantrips if you are just trying to do damage. You didn't specify your class, but:

- Poison Spray does 1d12 damage
- Firebolt 1d10 (and 120ft range, and lighting things on fire)
- Chill Touch 1d8 (and target can't regain HP)
- Ray of Frost 1d8 (and target's speed is reduced).

I would think all of these would be superior to Create Bonfire, but circumstances could make it the better choice. You do get the option of creating a choke-point with it.

Comment: Poison Spray is definitely inferior because of its [damage type](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/103214/9552) _and_ it has horrible range.

Comment: Firebolt, Chill Touch, and Ray of Frost are ranged attacks and can crit as well. While the damage type does suck, Poison Spray looks a little better if you think of it like a melee attack with reach instead of a ranged attack with tiny range.

Comment: Create Bonfire does have one advantage over all the cantrips you listed: if you maintain concentration, it remains in place and forces anyone entering that space to make the save or take the damage. With clever use of the terrain and/or forced movement, this can mean more damage overall, as well as the chokepoint option that you noted.

Comment: FYI This was in the context of creating a druid, so unfortunately only Poison Spray would fit, and the damage type is of concern!

Comment: A note against create bonfire: It kills any OTHER concentration spells you may have!

Answer (score 11):

### Yes

There is no limitation to how often a cantrip can be cast, or against re-targeting the same area. The only limitation is that you must stop concentrating on the last bonfire cast in order to cast it again.

The main drawback is if you are currently concentrating on a different (higher level) spell, you would have to stop concentrating to cast your cantrip. It is common for a caster to start with a concentration spell then fall back to spamming a damage cantrip while they concentrate, but that formula doesn't work with *Create Bonfire*.

Comment: Do you have a source for "The main drawback is if you are currently concentrating on a different (higher level) spell, you would have to stop concentrating to cast your cantrip"? This just came up in my game, and I can't find a rule that says you have to stop concentrating on the first spell. You could cast Bonfire for the 1d8 initial damage, and choose to concentrate on your initial spell, having the Bonfire go out immediately.

Comment: @Jorn from the basic rules: https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#:~:text=You%20lose%20concentration%20on%20a,that%20requires%20concentration.