# What creatures have the regeneration ability?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, regeneration

I am searching throughout all the different books to find the creatures with the regeneration ability. I am not particularly interested in special regeneration (Such as a hydras head regrowth or a Phoenix rebirth). I need help finding all my options for creatures with strait regeneration such as a Troll or Vampire. The higher the regeneration the better.

Alright context. I am a player in an obnoxiously homebrewed game. Our characters are a combination of 3 different creatures and we choose traits to apply to our characters from each creature. I am creating a few background characters because this is a chaos campaign and our dm throws crazy powerful stuff at us to attempt to provide us with a challenge (and occasionally goes overboard). I am trying to find creatures with the regeneration feature so that I can apply it to one of my backups. I want some options because we already have 2 vampires (One of them being my character) and I want to find one that fits the thematic of the new character. They are a combination of a Phoenix and an Air Elemental Myrmidon so far. I am trying to find a creature with regeneration that fits this theme.

Comment: Are you talking about monsters only, or NPCs as well, and/or other creatures too?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In which situations would the ability to prevent creature healing be most useful?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122054/in-which-situations-would-the-ability-to-prevent-creature-healing-be-most-useful)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A full list of the current creatures that are not adventure NPCs that have the Regeneration trait:

Knight of the Order - CoS (*Curse of Strahd*)

Belashyrra - E:RftLW (*Eberron: Rising from the Last War*)
Dyrrn

Devkarin Lich - GGR (*Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica*)
Jarad Vod Savo

Demogorgon - HftT (*Hunt for the Thessalhydra*)

Blue Slaad - MM (*Monster Manual*)
Death Slaad
Gray Slaad
Green Slaad
Oni
Red Slaad
Revenant
Shield Guardian
Troll
Vampire
Vampire Spawn
Vampire Spellcaster
Vampire Warrior

Bael - MTF (*Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes*)
Dire Troll
Geryon
Hutijin
Juiblex
Moloch
Spirit Troll
Titivilus
Venom Troll
Zariel

Vampire Neonate - PSI (*Planeshift: Innistrad*)

Aquatic Troll - RoT (*The Rise of Tiamat*)
Ice Troll

Dragonpriest - TftYP (*Tales from the Yawning Portal*)
Scrag

Stone Juggernaut - ToA (*Tomb of Annihilation*)
Yellow Musk Creeper

Frost Giant Everlasting One - VGM (*Volo's Guide to Monsters*)
Spawn of Kyuss
Thorny
Vegepygmy
Vegepygmy Chief
Warlord*
Wood Woad

Bore Worm - WDMM (*Waterdeep: Dungeon of the Mad Mage*)
Five-Armed Troll

---

One way to find *some* of these monsters would be by using DnD Beyond and searching for "Regeneration" and filtering for monsters ([example search](https://www.dndbeyond.com/search?q=regeneration&f=monsters&c=monsters)). The problem is that this only lists the first 35 results and not all of them. Thanks so much to [@Someone_Evil](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/52137/) for pointing this out!

---

* The Warlord basically has the Regeneration trait but it is slightly different and called Survivor:

> The warlord regains 10 hit points at the start of its turn if it has at least 1 hit point but fewer hit points than half its hit point maximum.

Credit to [@Someone_Evil](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/52137/) for finding this monster

Comment: How did you go about obtaining this list and how can one do it?

Comment: @Someone_Evil Personal tables for some bits, but if I'm being honest it was through less-than-legal sources and sorters. I could not find any way to do this on DnD Beyond

Comment: You might want to add searching for "regeneration" and filtering for monsters, ([example](https://www.dndbeyond.com/search?q=regeneration&f=monsters&c=monsters) but since it limits to 35 results it doesn't return all of them

Comment: @Someone_Evil Oh I didn't even know you could search monster statblock text, that's awesome!

Comment: @Someone_Evil Added it in now, the feature is nearly identical