# Does non-elemental magic damage exist on offensive projectiles?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, damage

I'm thinking of creating an cantrip called *mana bullet*, similar in damage to *fire bolt*, that is made of pure mana - and as such is non-elemental, and can't be affected by elemental resistance. Of course, magic resistance still affects it. I'll lower the damage to balance out the fact that elemental resistance has no effect on it. I just wanted to know if such a thing is possible on a projectile spell of offensive nature.

What I mean by "projectile":

*Fire bolt* or *fireball* as well as *magic stone* are considered projectiles to me. My definition of "projectile" is basically the Skyrim definition. A projectile is simply an object that is launched in any way. Arrows, thrown rocks, *fireball*, all classify. Something like a summoning spell, vine whip, sprays or beams, are all not "launched".

Comment: What do you mean by projectile spell? A spell that uses a ranged attack? Or a spell that involves an actual projectile (based on the spell description)?

Comment: Your definition of "Projectile", and how you want to separate it, doesn't quite work in DnD 5th Edition. For example,  Ray of Frost (a "laser") and Fire Bolt (a "projectile") are almost identical in DnD5e.  Alternatively, Fireball has more in common with the Catapult (throws rocks) and Vine Whip spells than it does with Fire Bolt.  While there is a difference between an Attack and a Saving Throw spell, there's nothing in the game that matches your definition of a "Non/Projectile".

Comment: @DanielZastoupil don't really see where the logic for fireball being similar to vine which comes in can you explain

Comment: Just a note regarding your recent edit: It's good to clarify what you mean in the question, but your edit shouldn't be a response to the comment - i.e. it should stand on its own within the question, rather than being reliant on the comment it's "responding" to to make sense.

Comment: Also, [*fire bolt*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fire-bolt) is not an "object" by the game definition (though you do "hurl" it, per the spell description)... The same is true of [*fireball*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fireball) (though the only thing "launched" is a "bright streak [that] blossoms with a low roar into an explosion of flame" at the targeted point). ...Also, given your definition, I don't see how *fire bolt* would qualify but "beams" wouldn't.

Comment: Is the "projectile" part of this question necessary? Because that's where the close votes are coming from. Would you be happy with just, "Are there spells that deal non-elemental magic damage?"

Comment: You only mention cantrip in your question body. Does non-cantrip spell satisfy your requirement? If it doesn't, maybe better update the title with "only cantrip"

Comment: @MageintheBarrel Sorry, you're correct on the correlation between Thorn Whip and Fireball.  Thorn Whip uses an attack (as does Fire Bolt), where I was thinking of Lightning Lure which uses a saving throw (as does Fireball).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### There is some precedent

I'll be considering "elemental damage" to be the damage types that show up in place like *absorb elements* and Elemental Adept. As such, there are 9 cantrips that deal non-elemental damage at range.

Here are the ones that perform ranged attacks (i.e. projectiles):

- *chill touch*
- *eldritch blast*
- *magic stone*

Here's one that performs a melee spell attack at 30 feet away:

- *vine whip*

And here are the ones that cause saving throws:

- *infestation*
- *poison spray*
- *sacred flame*
- *toll the dead*
- *vicious mockery*

### How much damage can they do?

It sounds like your proposed *mana bolt* homebrew would use force damage:

> Force is pure magical energy focused into a damaging form.

As such, the most obvious comparison is *eldritch blast* which deals 1d10. However, *eldritch blast* is warlock exclusive and is designed to be a bit better than wizard cantrips (consider how it compares to *firebolt*). As such, *mana bullet* should be somewhat weaker than *eldritch blast*.

Another comparison to draw is to *chill touch*, the only official wizard "projectile" cantrip. Necrotic damage is [marginally more resisted](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/103213/41726) compared to force damage. As such, *mana bullet* should be marginally less effective than *chill touch*. Removing the secondary benefit would satisfy this.

So *mana bullet* should probably deal around 1d8 force damage with a long range. (Could probably move up to 1d10 but only if the range was cut back quite a bit).

Comment: I might also  add that a reflex save seems appropriate given the nature of the attack

Comment: @IronGremlin There are no Reflex saves in 5e and most projectile based concepts are handled as ranged attacks not saving throws

Answer (score 5):

### Use *eldritch blast* or *magic stone*

*Eldritch blast* is an attack cantrip that deals non-elemental damage that is not often resisted (force).

*Magic stone* creates projectiles and enables you to make magical attacks that deal bludgeoning damage, which is also rarely resisted (although not as rarely as force).

Comment: eldritch blast is similar to what im looking for but is a watlock spell and id rather be a wizard or sorcerer and magic  stone requires  a sling which feels very un wizard like. Are there any wizard spells that don't required an alternate weapon but deal non-elemental damage i wouldn't mind magic stone if i can just throw it – Mage in the Barrel 5 mins ago    delete

Comment: @MageintheBarrel magic stone can be thrown too (but it is also druid/warlock exclusive)