# Which conditions are the most monsters immune to, and which are the fewest immune to?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, conditions, immunities

Related to this question: [What are the most and least-resisted damage types?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103213/what-are-the-most-and-least-resisted-damage-types)

Which conditions are the most monsters immune to? And which conditions are the fewest monsters immune to?

I was looking at the [UA psionic spells](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-PsychicSoulPsionics.pdf#page=7), and I saw that Id Insinuation causes the incapacitated condition. It got me thinking about how often, if ever, a creature is immune to the incapacitated condition. I use a lot of creatures that seem to have immunities to the same conditions, while other conditions are rarely in the list of immune conditions.

Comment: Also do note that just because X% of monsters are immune to, say, Poisoned, that doesn't mean X% of reasonable and encounterable monsters are. They could all have similar CR or all be of a type less commonly found in any given campaign. Are you more just curious about the raw numbers than the distribution based on actual use/appearance? See the two answers to the linked question and how different they are

Comment: @Medix2 I am interested in something similar to the accepted answer on the linked question regardless of how often a creature may be encountered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Most: Poisoned (434). Least: Incapacitated (1); Unconscious (26).

As of the writing of this answer, there are 1652 total monster/NPC statblocks listed on D&D Beyond.

We can use the filtering options in [D&D Beyond's monster listing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters) to see how many monsters/NPCs across all sources are immune to each condition:

- [Blinded](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-condition-immunity=1): 97
- [Charmed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-condition-immunity=2): 290
- [Deafened](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-condition-immunity=3): 79
- [Exhaustion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-condition-immunity=4): 266
- [Frightened](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-condition-immunity=5): 290
- [Grappled](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-condition-immunity=6): 61
- [Incapacitated](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-condition-immunity=7): 1 (the [warforged colossus](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/warforged-colossus) from E:RftLW, p. 314)
- [Invisible](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-condition-immunity=8): 0 - That said, it doesn't really count because it's not a
  negative condition that's ever forced on an unwilling creature.
  (Presumably it's only listed as a condition so features/spells don't
  have to repeat the effects of invisibility over and over.)
- [Paralyzed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-condition-immunity=9): 194
- [Petrified](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-condition-immunity=10): 148
- [Poisoned](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-condition-immunity=11): 434
- [Prone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-condition-immunity=12): 124
- [Restrained](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-condition-immunity=13): 62
- [Stunned](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-condition-immunity=14): 39
- [Unconscious](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-condition-immunity=15): 26

Ignoring the outlier that is the **Invisible** condition:

The condition that the most number of monsters listed on DDB are immune to, by far, is the **Poisoned** condition, with 434 listed monsters that have an immunity to it. The conditions with the next highest number of monsters immune to it are **Charmed** and **Frightened**, with 290 monsters (there's obviously overlap, but the lists aren't identical).

The condition that the fewest monsters are immune to is easily the **Incapacitated** condition; only the warforged colossus is directly immune to it. After that, monsters are least often immune to the **Unconscious** condition, with 26 monsters listed, and the **Stunned** condition, with 39 monsters immune to it.

---

**Note:** DDB's monster listing now lists specific variants of monster statblocks (e.g. an adventure taking an existing monster and making modifications to its traits or attacks) separately from the base statblock, though it did not do so when it first began listing monsters. As a result, these numbers might be slightly overestimating the actual number of monsters excluding such variants - but I suspect the difference won't be enough to change the relative rankings between conditions.

Answer (score 7):

[This spreadsheet lists the number of monsters from the *Monster Manual*, *Volo's Guide to Monsters*, and *Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes* that are immune to each condition.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X70jdBX0X0n_5V7stc1_kYERXLNGJIbdjhl3BUbKxQI/edit#gid=0)

According to the spreadsheet:

- The most creatures have immunity to the Poisoned condition
- The fewest creatures have immunity to the Unconscious condition
- And (based on my D&D beyond search) 1 whole creature immune to
  incapacitated.

This spreadsheet only has monsters from those 3 books, but I think it gives a very good idea of where these immunities are weighted.