# Which damage types are the most and least common?

Tags: monsters, pathfinder-2e, damage-types

(inspired by [these](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/179500/9552) [questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/179613/9552))

I have already asked which *physical* damage type is the most common, but how does it look when we consider all of them?

I mean the damage directly dealt by monsters, and the typical spells they can use. Items that are an integral part of the monster (like a Solar's greatsword or longbow) should be included.

Comment: Are you asking not about what is the most common when playing, which is up to the GM, but rather "among all the attacks of all published monsters, which damage types are the most common"?

Comment: @From, yes, just like the two referenced questions

Comment: _Typical_ spells are fine, but some monsters could learn any spell of their level

Comment: This seems like a lot of work, so you'll probably be more likely to have someone do it if you put up more than the minimum of 50 rep for the bounty.

Comment: Also, should this specifically address "energy" damage? Otherwise it's almost definitely going to mirror the question about physical damage since nearly all Creatures have some form of basic Strike that deals physical damage (with the exception of ghosts/spirits and a few others) and *maybe* another type. It's also a whole additional level if we try to consider what type of damage a creature is *expected* to do vs. can do. And it probably matters what level range you look at, to some extent. Adding energy or alignment damage to Strikes becomes very popular around level 8-12.

Comment: @Ifusaso the question is "in which order should I buy items granting resistances?"

Comment: @András If you don't know at least what creature family you're up against it's not going to be economical to buy any energy resistance gear

Comment: @MatthewWells, depending on your level a Ring of Fire Resistance might be trivially cheap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data from [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SpzEGKgmPNI3fxab4wQtPZm8weqXDgAJeIubIiU-B4U/edit#gid=306188899) contains Bestiary 1-3, and some other sources

| Type | Count V | Type Ʌ | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Piercing | 1446 | Acid | 77 |
| Bludgeoning | 939 | Bleed | 63 |
| Slashing | 937 | Bludgeoning | 939 |
| Magical | 742 | Chaotic | 43 |
| Fire | 180 | Cold | 59 |
| Persistent | 130 | Electricity | 69 |
| Evil | 128 | Evil | 128 |
| Force | 110 | Fire | 180 |
| Negative | 80 | Force | 110 |
| Poison | 78 | Good | 34 |
| Acid | 77 | Lawful | 12 |
| Electricity | 69 | Magical | 742 |
| Bleed | 63 | Mental | 25 |
| Cold | 59 | Negative | 80 |
| Chaotic | 43 | Persistent | 130 |
| Good | 34 | Piercing | 1446 |
| Mental | 25 | Poison | 78 |
| Sonic | 20 | Positive | 11 |
| Lawful | 12 | Slashing | 937 |
| Positive | 11 | Sonic | 20 |